# What kind of Undefined control sequence error is this and what is the solution?

Tags: strut

I am using overleaf and getting following Error massage:

```
\f@nch@och ->\conftitle 
                        \strut 
l.176 
      
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Preambles are:

```
\renewcommand{\encodingdefault}{OT1}

\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\renewcommand\IEEEkeywordsname{Keywords}
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.


\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{multirow}



%for ending the para equally
\usepackage{flushend}
%for marking authors with 1, 2 ,3 in upperscript
\newcommand\Mark[1]{\textsuperscript#1}

%to put a line in the middle of a figure
\newcommand{\rulesep}{\unskip\ \vrule\ }

\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
    T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
    
\makeatletter
%for adding footer
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
%\def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
%  \def\@oddfoot{\mycopyrightnotice}%
%  \def\@evenfoot{}%
%}

%\def\mycopyrightnotice{%
% {\footnotesize  978-1-7281-6099-3/19/\$31.00 \textcopyright2019 IEEE\hfill}% <--- Change here
%  \gdef\mycopyrightnotice{}% just in case
%}
   %%978-1-7281-3060-6/19/$31.00 ©2019 IEEE 

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\AtPageUpperMyright[1]{\AtPageUpperLeft{%
 \put(\LenToUnit{0.5\paperwidth},\LenToUnit{-1cm}){%
     \parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\raggedleft\fontsize{9}{11}\selectfont #1}}%
 }}%
\newcommand{\conf}[1]{%
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
\AtPageUpperMyright{#1}
}
}

%This part is for adding copyright in left of first page and page number in right alignment.
% insert page header and footer here for IEEE PDF Compliant
\fancypagestyle{pageStyleOne}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhead[C]{\conftitle}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}    % do you want page number on the first page?
    \fancyfoot[L]{978-1-6654-4911-3/21/\$31.00 \copyright2021 IEEE}
}

\fancypagestyle{pageStyleTwo}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhead[C]{\conftitle}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}    % do you want page number on the first page?
}
%upto this part




\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}


\setcounter{page}{71}



\begin{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `\fancyhead[C]{\conftitle}` to put `\conftitle` in the page head but have not defined it. It is presumably intended to be a conference title, add

```
\newcommand\conftitle{some conference}
```